# Team City 7.0 - How do you configure builds dependent on a shared compiled library?

Tags: teamcity, teamcity-7.0

This is my first attempt at setting up a Build Configuration in Team City.

In Subversion all third party binaries are stored in a separate repository called Applications because it is shared.

So on my local machine the path is

```
D:\Dev\SolutionRoot\WebProjectRoot
```

which has references to binaries in

```
D:\Dev\Applications
```

In Team City I have two build configurations (one to build the project (.sln) and one to just check out the third party binaries).

For the web project build configuration I added an Artifact Dependency which Depends On "Get Third Party Binaries", Gets artifacts from "Last successful build" and Artifact rules:

```
/*/.=>Applications
```

The build fails trying to resolve the artifact dependencies.

```
Build 'Furniture :: Build' #528 
Started 'Thu Aug 09 15:13:50 BST 2012' on 'machine name' by 'Ryan'
Finished 'Thu Aug 09 15:14:09 BST 2012' with status 'FAILURE Artifacts resolving failed'
TeamCity URL http://localhost:8111/viewLog.html?buildId=14&buildTypeId=bt2 
TeamCity server version is 7.1 (build 23907)

[15:13:50]: bt2 (18s)
[15:13:50]: Checking for changes (running for 4m:57s)
[15:13:50]: Publishing internal artifacts
[15:13:50]:  [Publishing internal artifacts] Sending build.start.properties.gz file
[15:13:50]: Clearing temporary directory: C:\TeamCity\buildAgent\temp\buildTmp
[15:13:50]: Clean build enabled: removing old files from C:\TeamCity\buildAgent\work\a3a48aff6a8b3347
[15:13:50]: Checkout directory: C:\TeamCity\buildAgent\work\a3a48aff6a8b3347
[15:13:50]: Updating sources: agent side checkout (18s)
[15:13:50]:  [Updating sources] Will perform clean checkout. Reason: Checkout directory is empty or doesn't exist (running for 4m:56s)
[15:13:50]:  [Updating sources] Cleaning C:\TeamCity\buildAgent\work\a3a48aff6a8b3347
[15:13:50]:  [Updating sources] VCS Root: Furniture (18s)
[15:13:50]:      [VCS Root: Furniture] revision: 528_2012/08/09 12:00:34 +0100
[15:14:09]: Resolving artifact dependencies
[15:14:09]:  [Resolving artifact dependencies] Failed to resolve artifact dependency <Furniture :: Get Third Party Binaries, build #2 [id 10]>: No files matched for patterns "/*/.=>Applications" from <Furniture :: Get Third Party Binaries, build #2 [id 10]> (jetbrains.buildServer.artifacts.ResolvingFailedException)
[15:14:09]:  [Resolving artifact dependencies] Failed to resolve 1 of 1 artifact dependencies
[15:14:09]: Failed to resolve 1 of 1 artifact dependencies
[15:14:09]: Publishing internal artifacts
[15:14:09]:  [Publishing internal artifacts] Sending build.finish.properties.gz file
[15:14:09]: Build failed to start. Artifacts will not be published for this build
[15:14:09]: Build finished
```

Have I done this correctly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see several problems in your setup.

First of all to introduce artifact dependency you should [publish those artifacts](http://confluence.jetbrains.net/display/TCD7/Build+Artifact) in source configuration (in your case - config, which checkout third party libraries).

Then, you should not actually use artifact dependency to just checkout sms.
TeamCity support [attaching of several VCS roots](http://confluence.jetbrains.net/display/TCD7/Configuring+VCS+Settings) to the configuration.

So in your case you could have single configuration with two roots attached: root with your sources, root with libs. Also you could use [checkout rules](http://confluence.jetbrains.net/display/TCD7/VCS+Checkout+Rules) to form any [checkout directory](http://confluence.jetbrains.net/display/TCD7/Build+Checkout+Directory) structure you need.